# Display user requested columns with google-sheets api for a Discord Bot in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, google-sheets-api

I'm making a Discord Bot for a final project. It is in javascript. For this part of the bot I need to be able to read (query) a google-sheet that will ideally have stats on it. I would like to stick with the google API, javascript, discord.js; I don't want to add another dependency or library or whatever. I can communicate with the google-sheets-api. I want to be able to take a user's input (from discord) and return the columns that they request. This is what I have..

```
if (msg.content === 'ricky list names') {
    client.commands.get('showNames').execute(msg);
  }
  /**else if (parts[1] === 'list' && humans.some(v => content.includes(v))) {
    if (parts[2] === 'first')
      client.commands.get('ageYear').execute(msg)
    else if (parts[2] === 'last')
      client.commands.get('lastName').execute(msg)
    else if (parts[2] === 'age')
      client.commands.get('personAge').execute(msg)
    else if (parts[2] === 'year')
      client.commands.get('yearBorn').execute(msg);
    }
  else if (parts[1] === 'list' && humans.some(v => content.includes(v))) {
  if (parts.indexOf('first') === 2)
    client.commands.get('ageYear').execute(msg)
  else if (parts.indexOf('first') === 3)
    client.commands.get('ageYear').execute(msg)
  else if (parts.indexOf('first') === 4)
    client.commands.get('ageYear').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('last') === 2)
      client.commands.get('lastName').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('last') === 3)
      client.commands.get('lastName').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('last') === 4)
      client.commands.get('lastName').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('age') === 2)
      client.commands.get('personAge').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('age') === 3)
      client.commands.get('personAge').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('age') === 4)
      client.commands.get('personAge').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('year') === 2)
      client.commands.get('yearBorn').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('year') === 3)
      client.commands.get('yearBorn').execute(msg)
    else if (parts.indexOf('year') === 4)
      client.commands.get('yearBorn').execute(msg)
  }*/
  else if (parts[1] === 'list' && humans.some(v => content.includes(v))) {
    content.forEach(function (item, index) {
      console.log(item, index)
    });
  }
```

I am stuck--very clearly. I have the content of the message divided up, but it's like, I'm running circles in my head with the loops.

Comment: I don't get what is your problem. If you want to read and write using the API there are a ton of already answered questions. I think you could read the [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: My problem is if someone asked the bot to "display columns a, d, e, f,"  i don't know how to make my bot do that. I know that there is a ton of already answered questions. I have been at this for 2 months, and the amount of research that I've done is astounding, which includes GitHub and stack overflow. I've searched different keywords, and I am coming here, to stack overflow at this point because I need help.